# Como escrever um ficheiro de texto clicando num DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Eu tenho um `DataGridView` e ao clicar nesse `DataGridView` tenho de escrever num ficheiro um `select` comparando uma coluna de uma tabela a outra coluna de outra tabela e o que resultar desse `select` é o que eu tenho de escrever no ficheiro.

Isto é como eu estou a escrever no ficheiro neste momento mas não está bem feito pois está a escrever o que mostra no `DataGridView`.

```
if (dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
     foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows)
     {
         var transactionHandler = new TransactionHandler();
         FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\HP8200\\Desktop\\faturas\\" 
                   + r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() 
                   + r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() 
                   + r.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ".txt");
         using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(arquivo.FullName,false,Encoding.Default))
         {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridViewEnviarDados.Columns)
            {
                  tw.Write(r.Cells[c.Name].Value.ToString() +";");
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Isto é como tem de estar o `datagrindview`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o select que eu estou usando é este :

```
SELECT  X.[TransDocument], X.[TransSerial],X.[TransDocNumber], I.[CreateDate], I.[PartyFederalTaxID], I.[TotalAmount], 
I.[ShipToAddressDetailLine1], I.[ShipToPostalCode], U.[ItemID], U.[TotalGrossAmount], U.[TotalNetPrintAmout], U.[Quantity], Y.[ItemID], Y.[BarCode], Y.[TaxableGroupID]

FROM
   [ELISAData].[dbo].[SaleTransaction] I
   INNER JOIN [ELISAData].[dbo].[SaleTransactionDetails] U
      ON I.[TransDocNumber] = U.[TransDocNumber]
      INNER JOIN [ELISAData].[dbo].[UXMenu] X
      ON U.[TransDocNumber] = X.[TransDocNumber]
      INNER JOIN [ELISAData].[dbo].[Item] Y
      ON U.[ItemID] = Y.[ItemID]

WHERE
   I.[TransDocNumber] = U.[TransDocNumber] AND
   X.[TransDocNumber] = U.[TransDocNumber] AND
   U.[ItemID] = Y.[ItemID]

   Order by [TransDocNumber]
```

Comment: Está dificil entender o que você precisa fazer!

Comment: Vou tentar me explicar melhor , eu preciso de fazer um ficheiro .txt , o conteúdo do ficheiro tem de ser o select da comparação de duas tabelas

Comment: @RovannLinhalis não entendi o que precisa desculpe

Comment: exatamente como a datagridview tem que ser exibida, estrutura das suas tabelas e os selects que você tem que executar

Comment: @RovannLinhalis já actualizei

Comment: o select, antes eram 2, já juntou com o inner join conforme havia comentado ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis porque eu queria facilitar a maneira de explicar faz só com duas tabelas eu tento adaptar, só meti esse select porque você pediu para por o select que eu uso

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64745/discussion-between-pedro-azevedo-and-rovann-linhalis).